# How to split the odd members of data to training set and multiples of 10 to test set in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, split, dataset

I have a dataset of 17000 instances with 3 attributes and a column for target values. I have to split the dataset that instances at odd numbers positions (1,3,5,7,..) will come in a training set data.frame and the instance number 10,20,30,40 will come in test set.

Answer (score 2):

Here an easy solution:

```
nrow<-nrow(df) #df is your dataset
training_set<-df[seq(1,nrow,by=2),] #select only odds rows
test_set<-df[seq(10,nrow,by=10),] #select only rows by 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%%` operator for indexing

Consider `x` is your data.frame

```
training_set <- x[seq_len(nrow(x)) %% 2 == 1, ]  # odds
test_set <- x[seq_len(nrow(x)) %% 10 == 0, ] # multiple of 10
```

Comment: Should there be two dimensions on that subsetting?  For example, `x[x %% 2 == 1, ]`

Comment: @Benjamin edited, thanks, initially I was considering a vector not a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a logical vector and recycling:

```
training_set <- df[c(TRUE, FALSE), ]
test_set <- df[c(rep(FALSE, 9), TRUE), ]
```

This works because `c(TRUE, FALSE)` recycles to the number of rows in the data frame, with only the odd positions resolving to `TRUE`.

Likewise, `c(rep(FALSE, 9), TRUE))` recycles, and only the multiples of ten resolve to `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest indexing with `seq` from base r to give a very simple and efficient approach:

```
df_train <- df[seq(1, 17000,  2), ]
df_test  <- df[seq(0, 17000, 10), ]
```

In the first example it is producing a vector which it uses to index taking every second number starting from 1 to 17000 (so all the odd numbers) and in the dftest set it is starting the sequence at zero and taking every tenth number. These are then position inside the square brackets to specify which `[rows, columns]` to call (with no columns specified it takes the entire row of the data frame.

Answer (score -1):

You can use operator `%%` for modulus.

Then it's straightforward:

```
train_set <- df[1:nrow(df) %% 2 == 0, ]
test_set <- df[1:nrow(df) %% 10 == 0, ]
```

If you intend to use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
train_set <- dt[1:(.N) %% 2 == 0]
test_set <- dt[1:(.N) %% 10 == 0]
```

Comment: how is  your answer different from mine?

Comment: I provided an answer: 
1) without seq_len which is not necessary 
2) considering a dataframe, not a variable (but you edited it afterwards as I see to use dataframe as well)
3) with data.table which is in my opinion a good practice